# Converting File Geodatabase Raster to TIFF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion

I am trying to export a raster file, saved as File Geodatabase Raster (FGDBR), as a .tif

The usual tools have not worked for me:

- data>export feature (resulting error: failed to create raster data set)
- raster to other format (to TIFF) (resulting in no file being created)

How do I export this File Geodatabase Raster as a .tif?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to provide details about *how* the usual tools "have not worked" starting with the exact product in use, and including any error messages as text in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Copy Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) tool to convert FGDB raster to TIFF format.

The [Raster to Other Format](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-other-format.htm), as you indicated trying, will also work as long as you follow the parameter requirements

The export features approach will not work in your case because you are working with raster data, not vector data.